# Convert String Uptime [d hh:mm] to Excel Time Value [hh:mm]

Tags: excel, vba, string, time

i need to convert the following records of Uptime format (d hh:mm)

```
8d 10:04
40d 11:19
148d 05:23
278d 23:43
1d 16:59
```

into the right Excel time value format (hh:mm) with hh being eventually higher than 24.
I need them to look like this:

```
202:04
971:19
3557:23
6695:43
```

Is there a function designed to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **B1** enter:

```
=--LEFT(A1,FIND("d",A1)-1)+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,99) & ":00")
```

[image]

Comment: It totally works. Thank you so much sir @Gary's Student